# Including wxwidgets in exrm build

Tags: elixir, exrm

How can I add the `wxwidgets` library to my Windows `exrm` build?  Currently, when I run my exrm-built application on Windows or try to use `:wx.new()`, I receive a message:

> ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function `:wx.new/0` is undefined (module `:wx` is not available)

Comment: Did you add `:wx` to the list of applications in `mix.exs`?

Comment: Yes, I added :wx to applications in mix.exs.

Comment: If you have further questions on using exrm, post your `mix.exs` file right away.  That's going to make a large difference in getting exrm working right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by adding a `relx.config` file to the `rel` directory in my project.  Getting the syntax right was a little challenging, but I noticed that `mix release` created a temporary `rel\.files` directory while it was running.  In that directory is a generated version of `relx.config` that you can use for reference.  Since the mix task takes a while to run, there is time to open that file and peek at its contents.

With an app named `foo`, the contents of the `relx.config` file was just one line:

```
{release,{foo,"0.0.1"},[{foo,"0.0.1"},elixir,iex,sasl,wx]}.
```

The only part I added was the ",wx".

I ran `mix release --prod` once again and then extracted the `rel\foo\releases\0.0.1\foo.tar.gz` file into a test directory.  From that test directory, `.\bin\foo console` ran my application with all the GUI working as expected.